# Having issues with setting up a matplotlib scatter graph

Tags: matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

plt.style.use("dark_background")
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.yscale("log")
plt.grid()
plt.xlim(1910, 2024)
plt.xticks(np.arange(1910, 2024, 10))
plt.ylim(1, 1000000000000)

plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(1))

year = [1920, 1924]
transistors = [8, 120]
names = ["placeholder", "placeholder"]

plt.title("Moore's law in 2024")
plt.xlabel("Year", fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel("# of transistors (log)", rotation=0, labelpad=50)

plt.scatter(year, transistors, c="darkred", marker=".", s=25)

for i in range(len(year)):
    plt.annotate(names[i], (year[i], transistors[i] - 0.2))

plt.show()
```

This is my code. I'm trying to make it, so that the y-axis has major points every power of 1, not like every power of 2, like it shows as in the graph (10 to the power of 2, 10 to the power of 4, etc...).
What would be nice too, is adding gray minor ticks and minor grids to the y-axis, which I couldn't find how to by myself, and also showing the last value on the x-axis (only show 2024, no other minor ticks).

Tried finding an answer online, but didn't find one.

Comment: "*major points every power of 1*" -- every power of 1 is 1.  Did you mean powers of 10?

Comment: In any case, you can set the *y*-axis ticks via `plt.yticks()`, much like you are setting *x*-axis ticks via `plt.xticks()`.  Each of these allows you to set both major and minor ticks.

Comment: `plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(LogLocator(numticks=12))` to have more y ticks. And `plt.tight_layout()` just before `plt.show()` to fit all labels nicely into the plot.

Comment: If I use yticks, it doesn't even load and says I need 78 or something terabytes, just saying I should use this command doesn't help. And yes, I meant powers of 10.